# Is it possible to hide properties from a derived class?

Tags: c#

Class A derive from class B. In class A I want to hide some properties inherited from class B. So when an instance is created of class A, I don't want to expose some properties from class B.

Is this possible?

Comment: Make it `private` instead of `public` or `protected`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that would defeat the purpose of inheritance. Your class A is a `B` , thus it has the properties of `B`

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to use private access specifier to your property which you want to hide?

if not, then please go through this link - might help you -
[c# hide from dervied classes some properties of base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338843/c-hide-from-dervied-classes-some-properties-of-base-class)

Answer (score 2):

You can shadow the members by declaring new ones with the same name (and the new modifier). But that doesn't really hide anything, and doesn't prevent anyone from casting back to B and accessing the members that way.

Are you sure you really want to use inheritance in this case? You may want to read up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Answer (score 2):

When you derive `A` from `B`, you're saying that `A` is practically the same as `B`, but it has additional characteristics; it is a specialization of `B`.

To make an example: a `Dog` is an `Animal`. In you're case, you're trying to say that an `Animal` has fins, but a `Dog` hasn't; this is definitely not the purpose of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

For achieving that, rather than working on making the property private, avoid inheritance and apply composition (i.e. use interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like:

```
class A {
    public virtual int X {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}

class B : A {
    public sealed override int X {
        get { return 2; }
    }
}

class C : B {
    public override int X {
        get { return -1; }
    }
}
```

If so, yes. (The above provides a compile-time error in `C`). The meaning here is that `A` had a property, `B` implemented it, and wanted to stop anyone sub-classes from doing so.