# How to hide methods from base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I use Castle Active Record' ActiveRecordBase class as a base class for my db objects. That allows me to take advantage of the AR pattern goodies, like:

```
MyClass clas = new MyClass();
clas.Number = 5;
clas.Save();
```

The problem is, for some objects, I want to hide these methods. How can I do that? I don't use interfaces for these objects.

Edit1:
To make it more clear: I want to have 10 classes inheriting from the base one, but 3 of them shouldn't expose some of the methods from the base class. So for example for MyClassB, this:

```
MyClassB clasB = new MyClassB();
clasB.Number = 5;
clasB.Save();
```

shouldn't be possible - this object SHOULDN'T be able to Save().

Edit2:
I've read [c# hide from dervied classes some properties of base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338843/c-hide-from-dervied-classes-some-properties-of-base-class) . I agree that this is bad approach, but bear in mind that I have to use ActiveRecordBase, which I cannot simply modify (at least if I want to stick with the original Castle Active Record sources).

Comment: What do you mean by hide, exactly?

Comment: So do you mean `MyClassB` should not have a `Number` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't do this.

You restructure your design so that the 7 objects inherit from one object that provides the functionality they want, the other 3 inherit from one that doesn't provide this, and they all inherit from the main "core" object. Think of it like a tree. Instead of trying to hide leaves from view, you simple change the location of the branch. I'm not sure this analogy works, but lets pretend it does.

Comment: @StupidDeveloper: Fair enough; if it's some requirement of your framework. I would suggest don't use a framework that requires that :) But that's probably not practical. Any solution you adopt will be non-ideal (i.e. access through some interface and only expose that, etc). Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide them, the probably do not belong in that base class. I suggest expanding the inheritance hierarchy to achieve this.